# Markdown, nested list : how to incorporate a nested list between two lines of a same list element

Tags: support, markdown, list

This is something I never managed to do with markdown. I write a list. In one of the elements, I am writing a paragraph, and then I want to list things again. So I create a nested list. So far so good. But then I want to continue writing on the same original item (of the first list). But the only way to keep the same implementation is to create a new list element, which I don't want to.

Example:

1. This is my a sentence, and then I will list stuff

   1. sublist first element
   2. sublist second element

I want this on the same level than the first element, but not as a new element.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want it to show [like this](https://i.imgur.com/gTg86xy.png)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this works:

```
1. test

   1. test
   2. test

   test
```

which produces

1. test

   1. test
   2. test

   test

So the trick is just to add some indentation (but not too much, or it will be interpreted as a code block).

Comment: Even whole code blocks can be indented using this method, though it's not super useful most of the time.

Comment: Yes this solves it on StackExchange. I am using a slightly different version of markdown than SE on another website and I thought that it would be the same problem, but this solution doesn't work there unfortunately.